# Appending to dictionary value, pythonesque solution

Tags: python, dictionary

Often, T form a dictionary in python whose keys are inserted dynamically and the values are some sort of lists:

```
dc = {'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar': [2,3,4]}
```

However, the generation of such a dictionary is problematic to me. For example, say I am going through this list:

```
l = [('foo', 1),('foo', 2),('foo', 3), ('bar', 2), ('bar', 3), ('bar', 4)]
```

And I want my program to generate the `dc` dictionary from above. For now, the only code I have is this:

```
dc = {}
for key, value in l:
    if dc.has_key(key):
         dc[key].append(value)
    else:
         dc[key] = value
```

Is there a more pythonesque way of doing this? There is a lot of code here that could really be squished to make one simple line, while not being cumbersome and/or slow...

**Edit** The list `l` above is there for illustration. In fact, I often go through a large file and find a key-value pair in each line of the file, so calling `dict(l)` is not an option.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Initializing_Dictionary_Elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dc = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in l:
    dc[key].append(value)
print dc
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': [2, 3, 4]})
```

You can use it just like using normal dictionary. But if you want to convert that to a dictionary, then you just do this

```
print dict(dc)
# {'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': [2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an answer I was hoping to get. Sorry I cannot accept two answers, as the one by @PauloBu is even more to my liking, but this one is also nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.setdefault#dict.setdefault) function as well.

```
>>>dc = {}
>>>for key, value in l:
>>>     dc.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)

>>>dc
{'bar': [2, 3, 4], 'foo': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I like this method better than the one by @thefourtheye (no imports here), although both are very good.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't have to be one iteration, whenever you have a key-value pair you can do the same. This answers OPs question.

Comment: @5xum: why is it better to do without imports? defaultdict is in the standard library, it's not an external dependency.

Comment: It's not that it's better, I just like it more. As I said, both solutions are good.